# Eat key in KeyDown

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.V Then
        If e.Control = True Then
            e.Handled = True 'eat it
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This does not work.
Does anybody know why and how to achieve the same in a proper way?

Thank you!

ps: Why is there a .Handled property that is writable, but it does not do anything? I guess I missed something.

Comment: Are you trying to disable a paste operation?

Comment: I believe he's trying to eat it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should capture the `KeyPress` event instead of `KeyDown`:

```
Private isCopyPaste As Boolean = False
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
     isCopyPaste = (e.KeyCode = Keys.V AndAlso e.Control)
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs ) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If isCopyPaste Then
        e.Handled = True 'eat it
    End If
End Sub
```

Also check this reference on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx

Comment: Ermh, KeyPress does not have these properties. KeyPress only has .KeyChar and .Handled.

Comment: Edited my answer, you should do the check in KeyDown and the actual cancel in KeyPress

Comment: Great answer, perhaps you could edit your reply as follows? ->         If e.KeyCode = Keys.V And e.Control = True Then
            m_bCopyPaste = True
        Else
            m_bCopyPaste = False
        End If

Comment: OK, even made it a little bit shorter for you :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use the SuppressKeyPress instead:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
  If e.KeyCode = Keys.V Then
    If e.Control = True Then
      e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Really cool, thank you, I didn't know that. However, Kenneth's answer fits my situation more.